# How to automate a jquery chosen dropdown using Selenium and java

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to automate selecting a specific option in following dropdown.

```html
<div class="form_element wrapper_horizontal invoiceLineCFA s-invoiceLineCFA">

 <label class="group_label" for="invoice_invoice_lines_attributes_1654466_custom_field_5_id">Category (Sourcing)</label>

 <select cf_editable="true" class="custom_field_select" data-ui-fn="chosen" data-ui-chosen-options="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;250px&quot;,&quot;disable_search_threshold&quot;:-1,&quot;no_results_text&quot;:&quot;No results match&quot;,&quot;placeholder_text_single&quot;:&quot;Select an Option&quot;,&quot;disable_browser_check&quot;:true,&quot;show_scope_of_selected_item&quot;:true,&quot;allow_single_deselect&quot;:true,&quot;search_contains&quot;:true,&quot;display_disabled_options&quot;:true,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;/lookup_values/auto_complete?limit=100\u0026lookup_id=9\u0026restricted=3\u0026show_groups=true&quot;}" name="invoice[invoice_lines_attributes][1654466][custom_field_5_id]" id="invoice_invoice_lines_attributes_1654466_custom_field_5_id" style="display: none;">
  <option value=""></option>
 </select>
 <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 250px;" title="" id="testid_chosen">
   <a class="chosen-single chosen-default chosen-single-with-test" tabindex="-1">
     <span>
       <ul class="chosen-scopes">
       <li>Select an Option</li>
      </ul>
     </span>
     <div>
      <b></b>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="hint">
 </div>
</div>
```

The options of this drpdown are in the bottom of the page which only appear in the DOM when click on the dropdown.

I am not able to click on the element to enable the options.
I tried Js click and webdriver click on the Div tag and anchor tag, both didn't work.

```js
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Please help.